# Install Local Configuration Store of Lync Server 2013

Tags: lync

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcgkR.png)My question is that when i'm trying to run the 1st step of Installing or Updating Lync Server System, it says that prerequisite installation failed: **SupportedOSNoDC**,
and the topology published successfully in order to run this step

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Here is the link for step by step installing Lync Server :http://windowspbx.blogspot.com/2012/07/step-by-step-installing-lync-server.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That means you are installing Lync on a domain controller, which will not work. Check the link below.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/23552f5d-0c46-4ce7-b44d-61b13fd65eb2/how-edit-bootstraplocalmgmt-for-not-checking-the-supportedosnodc-prerequisites-then-maybe?forum=ocsplanningdeployment

Comment: I have checked the link, but couldn't understand their solution. Can you explain step by step on how to manage this issue?